# Getting an object not found error but shouldnt this be declaring it?

Tags: r, object

Attempting to solve a problem in which i am setting up two models from given data, but when im attempting to do so its throwing the error `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'TimeSec' not found` why is this happening and how can i fix this? New to R coding

**CODE**

```
X<-read.csv("https://omega0.xyz/omega8008/ex4TLg.txt",head=T)
posterior1 <- MCMCregress(TimeSec~1, B0 = 1, data=X,marginal.likelihood="Chib95",mcmc = 100000)
plot(posterior1)
raftery.diag(posterior1)
summary(posterior1)



posterior2 <- MCMCregress(TimeSec~0+sqrt(LengthMt/GravityA),B0 = 1, data=X,marginal.likelihood="Chib95",mcmc = 100000)
```

**DATA**

```
"T" "L" "g"
"1" 3.35 1.9 9.796
"2" 2.21 1.84 9.827
"3" 2.73 1.83 9.803
"4" 2.39 1.8 9.822
"5" 1.13 0.24 9.811
"6" 1.73 0.53 9.821
"7" 1.42 0.42 9.818
"8" 1.5 0.49 9.792
"9" 1.99 1.41 9.816
"10" 1.92 0.96 9.809
"11" 3.36 1.95 9.806
"12" 2.43 0.88 9.835
"13" 1.1 0.47 9.806
"14" 2.76 0.76 9.817
"15" 1.16 0.53 9.796
"16" 2.97 1.77 9.84
"17" 1.96 1.08 9.798
"18" 2.98 1.41 9.818
"19" 2.52 1.48 9.831
```

Comment: Is there a column named `TimeSec` in dataframe `X`? What the error is saying is that no, there isn't a column `TimeSec` in `X`.

Comment: ahhh okay perhaps that is the issue, the data is listed as t.L,g, ill edit with the data but it can be seen at that link provided in the read.csv

Comment: Okay so just using T solved that issue but now for the second posterior its unable to find object "L"? why would this be

Comment: When I call that `read.csv` line, there's only one column with the name "T.L.g". You've got a problem with reading the data in—after reading it is a good time to check that things are in fact how you expect—in addition to the typos of referring to columns by names they don't have

Comment: It's not a CSV (**Comma** Separated Values) file, the separators are blank spaces. Try `X <- read.table("https://omega0.xyz/omega8008/ex4TLg.txt", header = TRUE)`. It works, I'm voting to close as off-topic/simple typo.